# Как сделать такой градиент? CSS

Tags: html, css, градиент

[image: Вот так должно получится]

Есть вот такой код :

```
html {
  .basket(#335, #dde, #aab, 40px);
}

.basket(@background, @to-right, @to-left, @size:25px) {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, @to-right 12%, transparent 0, transparent 88%, @to-right 0), 
              linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 37%, @to-left 0, @to-left 63%, transparent 0), 
              linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 37%, @to-right 0, @to-right 63%, transparent 0), 
              @background;
  background-size: @size @size;
}
```

Но я в нем ничего не могу понять, к сожалению
Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать данный градиент с помощью html/css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А что у Вас не получается? Что значит реализовать через css? весь код который Вы написали на css и он рабочий. Если вопрос в том почему ничего на экране не меняется, то прочитайте что такое [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) и для конкретной ситуации что такое миксины. Ниже код для Вас чтобы работал просто скопировав его)

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #dde 12%, transparent 0, transparent 88%, #dde 0), 
              linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 37%, #aab 0, #aab 63%, transparent 0), 
              linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 37%, #dde 0, #dde 63%, transparent 0), 
              #335;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Дело в том, что этот код я нашел на просторах интернета, а т.к. только сейчас узнал, что на основе CSS есть метаязыки, то разобраться в коде не получилось :(